# How can I set a string from variable as a key in existing object in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I know that this is working:

```
db.users.update({_id: "1234"}, {$set: {"conversations.partId": id}});
```

In result I've got: `conversations:{"partId":2345}`

but I would like to set partId as a variable. And to have structure like this: 
`conversations:{"3456":"2345"}`

I have tried:

```
db.users.update({_id: "someid"}, {$set: {"conversations".partId: id}});
or
db.users.update({_id: "someid"}, {$set: {"conversations"+partId: id}});
```

But this is of course not working

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the document you need to update via the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**, i.e.

```
var obj = {};
obj[partId] = id;
```

You can then use that as a new embedded document to add to the conversations field with the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator expression as follows:

```
db.users.update(
    {_id: "someid"}, 
    {
        $set: {
            "conversations": obj
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: thank you this is working. But is there a better way of adding another key:value than fetching from database existing key:value's, adding them to that obj and $set'ing conversation object from start? I'm thinking about something like $addToSet or $push but for objects

Comment: If you are updating the existing schema to have the key:value relationship then the only way is updating the embedded documents using a loop and if you are using MongoDB versions > 2.6 then [**bulk**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations can improve the performance. Other than that I don't see any other better way, and for the record, [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) or [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operators work on arrays.